# How to stop ads showing up on screen

Tags: ads

[image]

The phone is showing ads on the bottom of screen as well as on the top of whole screen 
I tried deleting the recent apps i installed 
I also tried disabling "show app on top" 
Is there any third party app that can scan the phone

Comment: Have you tried booting in Safe Mode to determine if the Ads still appear? In which case, you can be assured that no installed app is responsible for those Ads.

Comment: That must be some app with `Display over other apps` (SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission. Review all apps with this permission granted. Is your phone rooted?

Comment: When you found the culprit, and it's an app you've installed from Playstore, don't forget to report it. It's definitely violating the rules there (ads are only allowed to be shown in the app itself, not outside it).

Answer (score 3):

Possible reasons:

• Checkout Games that you installed recently.

• Check if you installed any app related to *Wallpapers or lock screen* category.

Because as far as i know Samsung doesn't have internal settings to show these horrible ads which covers the screen and affect their User Experience.

*In previous cases 'Games' are at top which is causing these types of ads.*

Comment: Free games and frees apps are responsible

Comment: There was an APP called Applock i have been using it since 2years

Comment: I think if you found the app and problem is resolved, you should answer yourself and accept it. Or lemme know to edit my answer to make it acceptable. So that coming members can be assured.